# How to identify specific rows in R (based on other values)

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, row, tidyverse

For my dataset I want a row for each year for each ID and I want to determine if they lived in an urban area or not (0/1). Because some ID’s moved within a year and therefore have two rows for that year, I want to identify if they have two rows for that specific year, which mean they lived in an urban and non-urban area in that year (so I can manually determine in Excel at where they belong).

I’ve already excluded the exact double rows (so they moved in a certain year, but the urbanisation didn’t change).

```
df <- df %>% distinct(ID, YEAR, URBAN, .keep_all = TRUE)




structure(t2A)
    # A tibble: 3,177,783 x 4
       ID ZIPCODE YEAR URBAN
            <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
     1   1 1234AB   2013     0
     2   1 1234AB   2014     0
     3   1 1234AB   2015     0
     4   1 1234AB   2016     0
     5   1 1234AB   2017     0
     6   1 1234AB   2018     0
     7   2 5678CD   2013     0
     8   2 5678CD   2014     0
     9   2 5678CD   2015     0
    10   2 5678CD   2016     0
    # ... with 3,177,773 more rows

structure(list(ID= c(1, 1, 1, 1
), YEAR = c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016"), URBAN = c(0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Can you guys help me with identifying ID’s that have two rows for a specific year/have a 0 and 1 in the same year?

Edit: the example doesn't show any ID's with urbanisation 1, but there are and not all ID's are included all years :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Hi Sotos, thank you for your anwser. I'm quite new to R and SO, I hope I adjusted my question right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below might be useful:

```
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID, YEAR) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(nIds=dplyr::n(),#count the occurance at unique ID and year combination
         URBAN_Flag=sum(URBAN), ##Urban flag for those who are from urban
         moved=dplyr::if_else(nIds>1,1,0)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-c(nIds))
```

You can deselect the columns if not needed

Comment: Hi Nirbhay, thank you for responding.I received this error: Error: n() should only be called in a data context. I might did something wrong with the names. You mention nIds; should this be nIDs or nID?

Comment: The reason you might get this error would be n() can be present in multiple packages.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Adding dplyr:: didn't work. I will restart R because I do have multiple packages. This will take some time (huge dataset).

Comment: I think you need to add dplyr at multiple places. I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm currently saving my workspace. After that I will restart R and try it with only the dplyr packages. In your code you state nIds, is this supposed to be nID or is this a function? Thank you

Comment: nIds is a new column name given by me, In general n refers for count /occurrences. So it will not be an issue.

Comment: Also, you don't require to restart the R, multiple packages can be present in an environment. Conflicts between loaded packages can be resolved by declaring your preference with the assignment as

`packagename::functionNames`

Comment: Thank you for all the information and you time! As soon as I run the code again, I will give you an update.

Comment: Hi Nirbhay, your code worked perfectly, thank you very  much!

Answer (score 0):

First, we create some dummy data

```
library(tidyverse)

db <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003),
  urban = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

We see that person one moved in 2000.

```
     id  year urban
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2000     0
2     1  2000     1
3     1  2001     0
4     2  2001     0
5     2  2002     0
6     2  2003     0
```

Now, we can group by `id` and `year` and count the number of rows. We can use the count value to create a dummy whether or not they moved in a given year.

```
db %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarize(rows = n()) %>%
  mutate(
    moved = ifelse(rows == 2, 1, 0)
  )
```

Which gives the result:

```
     id  year  rows moved
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1     1  2000     2     1
2     1  2001     1     0
3     2  2001     1     0
4     2  2002     1     0
5     2  2003     1     0
```

Comment: Hi, wow, great but big answer.. My dataframe contains over 250K ID's (and times max 6 years rows..) and I'm new to R: do I have to create dummy variables or was that just an example? And if so, how can I do that with so many unique values?

Comment: I received this comment while trying: Error: n() should only be called in a data context.. thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you will only have maximum of 2 rows per `id` `year` combination when you use your distinct. What we do is group by those variables and count the number of rows. The people with 2 rows will have moved within the year. You don't have to create the dummy variable, I just find it easier if what you want to do later is subset by these individuals. Did you try to run the code? You need to substitute my lower-case variables with your upper-case variables.

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly. I did change the names, my dataset is in another language. I received this error: Error: n() should only be called in a data context.. thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you able to run my MWE?

Comment: Im sorry, I don't know what that is.. I'm sure that the name I've put there is the name of my dataframe if that is what you mean. It also looks like a dataframe and has that table-figure for it's name above.